# App crashes on fresh install

Tags: android, google-maps

We've developed an app that is available now on Google Play but it has some minor bug in it.

You see, some devices report that our app crashes on fresh install.

The crash report is as follows:

> > java.lang.NullPointerException:    at com.atry.kil0b1te.sample.MapsActivity2.build_retrofit_and_get_response
> >     (MapsActivity2.java:259)   at
> >     com.atry.kil0b1te.sample.MapsActivity2.access$100
> >     (MapsActivity2.java:71)   at
> >     com.atry.kil0b1te.sample.MapsActivity2$2.run (MapsActivity2.java:163) 
> >     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:761)   at
> >     android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:98)   at
> >     android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:156)   at
> >     android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6605)   at
> >     java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)   at
> >     com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run
> >     (ZygoteInit.java:999)   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main
> >     (ZygoteInit.java:889)

IT refers to this method
build_retrofit_and_get_response method:

```
private void build_retrofit_and_get_response(String type) {

        String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/";

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(url)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        RetrofitMaps service = retrofit.create(RetrofitMaps.class);

        Call<Example> call = service.getDistanceDuration("metric", origin.latitude + "," + origin.longitude,dest.latitude + "," + dest.longitude, type);

        //showCoordinatesInfo();
        call.enqueue(new Callback<Example>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Response<Example> response, Retrofit retrofit) {

                try {
                    //Remove previous line from map
                    if (line != null) {
                        line.remove();
                    }
                    // This loop will go through all the results and add marker on each location.
                    for (int i = 0; i < response.body().getRoutes().size(); i++) {
                        String distance = response.body().getRoutes().get(i).getLegs().get(i).getDistance().getText();
                        String time = response.body().getRoutes().get(i).getLegs().get(i).getDuration().getText();
                        ShowDistanceDuration.setText("Distance: " + distance + "\nDuration: " + time);
                        String encodedString = response.body().getRoutes().get(0).getOverviewPolyline().getPoints();
                        List<LatLng> list = decodePoly(encodedString);
                        line = mMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
                                .addAll(list)
                                .width(10)
                                .color(Color.RED)
                                .geodesic(true)
                        );
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.d("onResponse", "There is an error");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
                Log.d("onFailure", t.toString());
            }
        });

        switch(type){
            case "driving":
                btnDriving.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.active_text));
                btnWalk.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
                break;
            case "walking":
                btnDriving.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
                btnWalk.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.active_text));
                break;
        }

    }
```

And to be specific the line 259 is:

```
Call<Example> call = service.getDistanceDuration("metric", origin.latitude + "," + origin.longitude,dest.latitude + "," + dest.longitude, type);
```

The **origin** is initialized on this method:

```
@Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        origin = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        float[] distance = new float[2];

        Location.distanceBetween(origin.latitude, origin.longitude, circle.getCenter().latitude,circle.getCenter().longitude,distance);

        if (distance[0] <= circle.getRadius() && !arrived)
        {
            arrived = true;
            markAsVisited();
            sendNotif();
            arrivalAlert();
        }

        switch (travel_mode){
            case "driving":
                build_retrofit_and_get_response("driving");
                break;
            case "walking":
                build_retrofit_and_get_response("walking");
                break;
        }
    }
```

This only happens on **fresh installs**! Do you have any ideas on how to fix this crash? Thank you.

Comment: Split line259 in different lines: until now you have no idea which object is null.

Comment: @Dominique The object that is null is the `origin.latitude` and/or `origin.longitiude` That's why I stated above how the `origin` object is being initialized.

Comment: I am getting frustrated because THIS specific crash only happens on fresh installs. It doesn't persists throughout the app's life on the mobile device.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the app by myself lol

The issue is caused by this line of codes in my Java class:

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            checkLocationPermission();
        }
```

So I moved that code to the startup of application. And now the crashes are fixed. Please do checkout our app [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.atry.kil0b1te.sample).